# Using ajax to store info from view to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have an "add friend" button on a profile page and I want it to, when clicked initiate an ajax request to create the friendship. I would need to send at least two parameters, the user's ID and ID of the user they're trying to befriend.

How do i retrieve the friend's ID?, Can I store it as a data attribute, next to their name, which gets retrieved via JQuery? then send it as one of the parameters to the ajax call? is this the appropriate way to do it? Is there a way to do this with XML

I'm going to put the js and html into one show.html.erb.js file, hope that's appropriate too.

EDIT
view content below. Note @p was generated by the controller and accessible in the view

```
<div class="profile" data-current=<%= current_user.id %>, data-id= <%= @p.user_id %> >
    <%= @p.first_name %> <%= @p.last_name %><br/>
    <button id="btnAddFriend">Add Friend</button>
</div>
```

show.js content below

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    alert("Hello");
    $("#btnAddFriend").click(function(){
        alert("Hello");
        addFriend();
    })

    var addFriend = function(){
        var friendId = $('.profile').attr('data-id');
        var user_id = $('.profile').attr('data-current');
        var Object=  {
        friendship: {
                user_id: user_id,
                friend_id:  friendId
             }
        }
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/users/" + user_id + "/friendships"+ friendId,
          data: JSON.stringify(Object),
          contentType: 'application/json',
          dataType: 'html',
          success: function() {
                $("#btnAddFriend").prop('value', 'Pending');
          }
        });
    }
});
```

Then the model action will receive the two parameters and use it to store the data. Please advise if this appropriate? Is there a better way to have the friend id transfer from the view to the ajax call, i.e. via xml?

Comment: can you paste the view code that has your ad friend button - it's easier to answer questions with code examples

Comment: Haven't created it, i'll update soon

Comment: Why do you want to use XML?

Comment: security reasons... If i don't have to expose the variables that I'm going to use in ajax calls to the client, i'd rather not. This will particularly be relevant in a later phase of the site. I want to know the most prevalent for doing something of this nature.

Comment: How does the controller's create action retrieve the data: JSON.stringify(Object) content?
And i'm getting an error that says its missing a create template, why is it insisting on one if i'm performing ajax call